# Angular 5 HttpRequest reportProgress

Tags: httprequest, angular5, microsoft-edge, progress

I have a block of code that when executed in every other browser including IE11 works just fine, but for whatever reason when Edge runs this code I don't get a progress like the other browsers.

Edge logs this:
progress-- true
event.type == 0

A long pause and then writes:
progress: true
loaded: xxx
total: xxx
type: 1

Code:

```
Upload(file : File, id:number, endPoint:string) : void {
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append(file.name, file);

    var auth = "Bearer " + this.Auth.GetAuth();

    var autoThumb = this.stagedThumb == null ? 'true' : 'false';

    const uploadRequest = new HttpRequest('POST', endPoint + `?id=${id}&thumb=${autoThumb}`, formData, {
      reportProgress: true,
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': auth
      })
    });

    this.PerformUpload(uploadRequest);    
  }

  PerformUpload(uploadRequest : HttpRequest<FormData>, progress: boolean = true) : void {
    this.http.request(uploadRequest).subscribe(event =>
    {
      console.log("Http Event Message -- Progress: " + progress);
      console.log(event);
      console.log("End Event Message");

      if (progress)
      { 
        if (event.type == HttpEventType.UploadProgress)
        {
          this.progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
        }
        else if (event.type == HttpEventType.Response)
        {
          this.message = event.body.toString();

          setTimeout(() => {
            this.ResetForm();
          }, 2*1000);
        }
      }  
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you have not found the root cause yet, it seems this is an open issue for MS Edge. 
See https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/12224510/